# Python: How Can I Render HTML Code And Show The Result To The User?

Tags: html, python-2.7, osx-yosemite

I'm building a python app that should get a certain HTML code, render it and display the result to the user in a tkinter gui. How can I do that? I would prefer having some built-in module, or some module which I can use easy_install to get. Thanks for any advance.

(I'm using OSX Yosemite with python 2.7)

Answer (score 8):

I've managed to render simple html tags using [tkhtml](https://bitbucket.org/aivarannamaa/tkinterhtml)

just `pip3 install tkinterhtml`

and, from the package [example](https://bitbucket.org/aivarannamaa/tkinterhtml/src/master/tkinterhtml/__main__.py?fileviewer=file-view-default):

```
from tkinterhtml import HtmlFrame
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = HtmlFrame(root, horizontal_scrollbar="auto")
 
frame.set_content("<html></html>")

frame.set_content(urllib.request.urlopen("http://thonny.cs.ut.ee").read().decode())
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: What is root here?

Comment: @SamZiggler `root = tk.Tk()` your tk root.

Comment: Nice. I tried it from there example but didn't render CSS stuff

Comment: @SamZiggler you're right, it can't handle CSS. I also faced this problem and then chose to use a flask app which is technically python.

Answer (score 4):

Save your HTML to a file location, and use the `webbrowser` module's `open()` function to display it; see https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html for documentation.

Comment: I really meant rendering the html in a html window.