# How to Integrate HTML in Python

Tags: python, html, css, renpy

It is necessary to integrate the html code in python so that it displays on output.

I searched all over the Internet, downloaded many different libraries, but they only do html code through python, and I needed it to be displayed on the screen.

Sample program:

```
#Could it look something like this?

import somelibrary

code = '''<!DOCTYPE html">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>sometitle</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>name</h1>
  <p>hello</p>
 </body>
</html>'''

somelibrary.show(code)
```

[What should be the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53os1.png)

If you know how to do this, or at least something like that, libraries that can help, please let me know.

Let's clarify the situation. I am making a game on Ren'py([link](https://www.renpy.org/)), and to simplify the work (I need to do something like a phone), I want to use HTML (CSS and JS). So I asked if I could somehow do what I want. I do not make my website.

Comment: You should check out `PyQt5`'s `QWebEngineView`.

Comment: Just use any Python HTTP and respond with your HTML and look at it in your browser.

Comment: Let's clarify the situation. I am making a game on Ren'py([link](https://www.renpy.org/)), and to simplify the work (I need to do something like a phone), I want to use HTML (CSS and JS). So I asked if I could somehow do what I want. I do not make my website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How Can I Render HTML Code And Show The Result To The User?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908340/python-how-can-i-render-html-code-and-show-the-result-to-the-user)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a **template engine** for python, that can dynamically generate html pages, and a server-side library that will help you send this html files to the client. 
for example, jinga (https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/) as template engine, and django as server-side library (as shina pointed out)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to checkout frameworks such as Flask (https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/) or Django (https://www.djangoproject.com/start/), they provide a neat way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django then use the djongo template viewer in order to add html to your code

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file, say `test.html`, and store the HTML content there.
Then open that file in your browser using below:

```
import webbrowser

# Open URL in a new tab, if a browser window is already open.
webbrowser.open('test.html')

# Open URL in new window, raising the window if possible.
webbrowser.open_new('test.html')
```

Note that webbrowser is not a core module therefore you'll have to install it first. Refer the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) for more details.